# ruby - omitting default parameter before splat

Tags: ruby

I have the following method signature

```
def invalidate_cache(suffix = '', *args)
  # blah
end
```

I don't know if this is possible but I want to call invalidate_cache and omit the first argument sometimes, for example:

```
middleware.invalidate_cache("test:1", "test")
```

This will of course bind the first argument to suffix and the second argument to args.

I would like both arguments to be bound to args without calling like this:

```
middleware.invalidate_cache("", "test:1", "test")
```

Is there a way round this?

Comment: How would you code *omit the first argument sometimes, for example:* run time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use keyword arguments (this works in Ruby 2.0+):

```
def invalidate_cache(suffix: '', **args) # note the double asterisk
  [suffix, args]
end

> invalidate_cache(foo: "any", bar: 4242)
=> ["", {:foo=>"any", :bar=>4242}]

> invalidate_cache(foo: "any", bar: 4242, suffix: "aaaaa")
=> ["aaaaa", {:foo=>"any", :bar=>4242}]
```

Note that you will have the varargs in a Hash instead of an Array and keys are limited to valid Symbols.

If you need to reference the arguments by position, create an Array from the Hash with `Hash#values`.

Comment: Fyi, keyword arguments are only supported in Ruby v2.0+.

Answer (score 0):

How about you create a wrapper method for `invalidate_cache` that just calls `invalidate_cache` with the standard argument for suffix.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, your code has to have some way of telling the difference between a suffix, and just another occurrence of args. E.g. In your first example, how is your program supposed to know that you didn't mean for `"test:1"` to actually be the suffix?

If you can answer that question, you can write some code to make the method determine at run time whether or not you provided a suffix. For example, say you specify that all suffixes have to start with a period (and no other arguments will). Then you could do something like this:

```
def invalidate_cache(*args)
  suffix = (args.first =~ /^\./) ? args.shift : ''
  [suffix, args]
end

invalidate_cache("test:1", "test") #=> ["", ["test:1", "test"]]
invalidate_cache(".jpeg", "test:1", "test") #=> [".jpeg", ["test:1", "test"]]
```

If, however, there actually is no way of telling the difference between an argument meant as a suffix and one meant to be lumped in with `args`, then you're kind of stuck. You'll either have to keep passing suffix explicitly, change the method signature to use keyword arguments (as detailed in [karatedog's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20952747/1157054)), or take an options hash.